# Multiple merges with loop for "by" variables

Tags: r, loops, merge, paste, assign

I want to make multiple merges: I have 38 files that I need to merge with one file, resulting in 38 merged files. Both `by.y` and `by.x` variables change according to each merge I want to make. In order to try to make all those merges in one loop, I've created three list of variables: (i) one that tells me what is the name of the file we will use to do the loop; (ii) one with the name of the `by.x` variables and (iii) one with the name of the variables for the `by.y` part.

Please see a reduced example of my problem with 3 data frames instead of 38:

```
(i) list_fam: c('f1990', 'f1991', 'f1992') #files to merge;
(ii) identifier_fam: c('f1','f2','f3') #by.x variables
(iii) identifier_ind: c('V1990','V1991','V1993') #by.y variables
(iv) ind: file to merge the list_fam
```

Tentative of loop 1:

```
for (i in list_fam){
  for (j in identifier_fam){
    for (k in identifier_ind){
      x<-paste("z",i,sep="")
      x<-merge( i, ind, by.x = j , by.y = k) 
}
}
}
```

Tentative of loop 2:

```
for (i in list_fam){
  for (j in identifier_fam){
    for (k in identifier_ind){
      x<-paste("z",i,sep="")
      assign(x, merge( i, ind, by.x = j , by.y = k)) 
}
}
}
```

In both cases, I receive the error:

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column.
```

Any clues what I may be coding wrong?

Comment: `assign` is generally a bad idea. Your example isn't reproducible, so I can't test to see if this works, but probably something along these lines will: `Map(merge, mget(list_fam), list(ind), by.x = identifier_fam, by.y = identifier_ind)`. Read `?Map` for details if you want to investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments `?Map` is what you are looking for:

```
Map(merge, mget(list_fam), list(ind),by.x=identifier_fam,by.y=identifier_ind)
```

**Reproducible Example**

```
set.seed(1116)
f1990 <- data.frame(f1 = sample(letters,10), col90=1:10)
f1991 <- data.frame(f2 = sample(state.abb,10), col91=1:10)
f1992 <- data.frame(f3 = sample(month.abb,10), col92=1:10)
ind <- data.frame(V1990=sample(letters,10), 
                  V1991=sample(state.abb,10), 
                  V1992=sample(month.abb, 10))
identifier_fam <- c('f1','f2','f3') #by.x variables
identifier_ind <- c('V1990','V1991','V1992') #by.y variables

Map(merge, mget(ls(pattern="f\\d{4}")), list(ind), by.x=identifier_fam, by.y=identifier_ind)
# $f1990
#   f1 col90 V1991 V1992
# 1  e     4    ND   Jul
# 2  g     2    OH   Nov
# 3  p     7    IA   May
# 4  s     6    SC   Sep
# 
# $f1991
#   f2 col91 V1990 V1992
# 1 MS     6     a   Feb
# 2 VT     8     o   Oct
# 
# $f1992
#    f3 col92 V1990 V1991
# 1 Apr     8     v    OK
# 2 Aug     3     z    FL
# 3 Feb    10     a    MS
# 4 Jul     4     e    ND
# 5 Jun     2     i    MN
# 6 May     5     p    IA
# 7 Nov     7     g    OH
# 8 Oct     1     o    VT
# 9 Sep     6     s    SC
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @PierreLafortune. Not only your solution was great but the work on the reproducible example was very good. It will certainly help me with my main issue and taught me on how to manage to create a good example.

Comment: I am sorry if this is a trivial question, but how do I "store" the merged files? Since we don't have a loop structure anymore I got a bit confused on how to do it in separate data frames (one for each merge). Thank you, again!

Comment: When we create the new list of merged data frames, for example `my_new_lst <- Map(merge, ..` We can then access each as a single data frame with `my_new_lst[[1]]` or whichever number we want.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much, @PierreLafortune!